# Как программно получить изображение значка ПУСК?

Tags: delphi

Как программно получить изображение значка ПУСК? Я пробовал вот так:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  btm:TBitmap;
  StartBtnWnd, StartBtnBmp: HWND;
begin
  StartBtnWnd:=FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil);
  StartBtnBmp:=FindWindowEx(StartBtnWnd, 0, 'Button', nil);
  btm:=SendMessage(StartBtnBmp, BM_GetImage, 0,Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Handle);
end;
```

Что не правильно? Компилятор пишет: Несовместимые типы Integer и TBitmap, указывая на предпоследнюю строчку на функции SendMessage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По ошибке: вы пытаетесь получить хэндл битмапа - HBITMAP, а не TBitmap. Это разные типы, о чем вам и сообщают.

По сути. Абсолютно правильного решения не знаю, поделюсь мыслями и подводными камнями. 
Получение картинки на кнопке пуск зависит от версии Windows.

**Для начала про "старые" винды** (например win2k3 сервер, xp видимо тоже).

Получить картинку с кнопки не получится (почему? - другой вопрос). Хэндл битмапа на SendMessage возвращается нулевой.

Остается вариант получать Device context (DC) функцией [GetWindowDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144947(v=VS.85).aspx) и копировать оттуда, делая как бы "скриншот". Код примерно такой:

```
function CreateWindowBitmap(Wnd: HWND): TBitmap;
var
  R: TRect;
  W, H: Integer;
  DC: HDC;
begin
  GetWindowRect(Wnd, R);
  W:=R.Right-R.Left;
  H:=R.Bottom-R.Top;
  DC:=GetWindowDC(Wnd);
  Result:=TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Result.Width:=w;
    Result.Height:=h;
    BitBlt(Result.Canvas.Handle,0,0,w,h,DC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
  finally
    ReleaseDC(Wnd, DC);
  end;
end;
```

Передавать в эту функцию нужно полученный ранее хэндл окна кнопки:

```
btm:=CreateWindowBitmap(
  FindWindowEx(FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil), 0, 'Button', nil);
```

**Дальше будет сложнее. Про 7ку речь.**

Тут кнопка "пуск", во-первых, является отдельным окном, ее нужно искать так:

```
FindWindow('Button','Start');
```

Во-вторых, это не поможет, т.к. кнопка также не имеет битмапа, на SendMessage тоже вернется 0. Да и анимация при наведении мыши на кнопку намекает, что врядли там дело в только в битмапе.

В-третьих, "скриншот" самой кнопки тоже снять не получится, вернется черный квадрат, без картинки.

Однако тут все же можно снять "скриншот". Только снимать его надо будет с окна Shell_TrayWnd.
Правда у этого окна размеры существенно больше, чем хотелось бы и придется брать размеры и положение самой кнопки, предварительно вычислив смещение одного относительно другого. Т.е. взять GetWindowRect для кнопки и подставить в BitBlt... (не буду расписывать тут подробно, должно быть несложно сделать).

Вот такие мысли, если кто-то предложит другой вариант, с интересом посмотрю.

Comment: До, ну если все же получится добиться от SendMessage правильного, ненулевого HBITMAP'а, то код будет выглядеть так:

    btm:=TBitmap.Create;
    btm.Handle:=SendMessage(StartBtnBmp, BM_GETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP,0);
    Image1.Picure.Bitmap.Assign(btm);
    btm.FreeImage;
    btm.Dormant;
    btm.Free;

Comment: Я просмотрел Ваш код, а потом переделал его на свой лад!

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь. Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

Я сам немного помудрил, вот что получилось:

```
var
  SDC: HDC;
  MCanvas :TCanvas;
  btm:TBitmap;
  StartBtnWnd, StartBtnBmp: HWND;
begin
  StartBtnWnd:=FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil);
  StartBtnBmp:=FindWindowEx(StartBtnWnd, 0, 'Button', nil);
  MCanvas:= TCanvas.Create;
  SDC:= GetDC(StartBtnBmp);
  MCanvas.Handle:=SDC;
  Image1.Canvas.CopyRect(MCanvas.ClipRect, MCanvas, MCanvas.ClipRect);
end;
```